# Вывести выбранный товар из mysql на отдельную страницу в php

Tags: php, mysql

как составить выборку вывода данных из mysql в php? Необходимо вывести выбранный товар и информацию о нем на отдельную страницу

Answer (score 1):

Составляете запрос на выборку, к примеру:

```
$product = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM 'orders' WHERE id = 1")->fetch_assoc();
```

Получите ассоциативный массив с информацией о Вашем товаре, например

```
$product = [
   'name' => 'Товар 1',
   'price' => 1000,
   ...
];
```

Затем в html коде делаете вывод в нужных местах:

```
<h1> Товар: <?= $product['name'] ?> </h1>
<br>
<h2> Цена: <?= $product['price'] ?> </h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Получить данные запросом (SELECT ...)
2. Результат преобразовать, например в массив
3. Вставить значения в вывод

Для этого Вам придется изучить PHP и работу с базой данных. Вопрос очень расплывчат для точной подсказки.

Comment: Вот потому что вопрос слишком расплывчат - на него не стоило отвечать. Обычно так и делают на so. Ваш ответ стоит преобразовать в комментарий.